# If statement in SQL-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm extending a stored procedure and I have to make some code that checks if a row contains 
some of the following then the SP will stop at the first stip which is this one. The SP contains of 6 steps and this is the first one. Which is used as a controller to see if the
row contains some if these. If it's doesent then it should continue to the next step. If it
does cointain some of the following then it should leave a notice and not contiune to the next step.

```
if @action = (select action from dbo.table where action like 'something-%')

if @action = (select action from dbo.table where action like 'something-else%')


if @action = (select action from dbo.table where action like 'something-new%')


if @action = (select action from dbo.table where action like 'something-old%')


if @action = (select action from dbo.table where action like 'something-cool%')
```

I have the first part need help with the second.

Cheers

Comment: Is the next step not a RETURN statement?

Comment: you should use `if...else if`. Using `CASE` might be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use [RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx):

```
if @action = (select action from dbo.table where action like 'something-%') begin
    RETURN;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement instead of many if statement.
Hope this example will Help

```
Simple CASE expression: 
    CASE input_expression 
         WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
         [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
    END 
    Searched CASE expression:
    CASE
         WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
         [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
    END
```

Comment: Given that the results are not necessarily mutually exclusive, would that mean potentially executing all the queries needlessly?